# Find cell content and copy row onto new sheet

Tags: excel, ms-word, row, cell, contains

I want to paste a list in the "InsertList" sheet. This list will only contain the word "Correct" or "False". From then on i need a way to search for the word "Correct" or "False" in the columnS P,Q,R,S,T,U,V.

e.g. If in the column "P" on the "InsertList" sheet the word "Correct" is found, i need that entire row from A to V to be copied onto it's destination, in this case "sheet1".

If the word "Correct" is found on the column "Q" on the "InsertList" sheet, the rows from A to V  need to be copied in the Sheet2. And so on..

[image]

Comment: What hapens if P,q,r and T all have the value correct?

Comment: That won't happen, i have some formulas in place to make sure of it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
For i = 2 to Thisworkbook.Sheets(“ÏnsertList”).Range(“A64000”).End(xlup).row

If  Thisworkbook.Sheets(“ÏnsertList”).Range(“P” & i).Value = “Correct” Then

Thisworkbook.Sheets(ÏnsertList”).Range(“A” & i & ":V" & i).Copy
 Thisworkbook.Sheets(“Sheet1”).Range(“A” & i)

ElseIf  Thisworkbook.Sheets(“ÏnsertList”).Range(“Q” & i).Value = “Correct” Then

Thisworkbook.Sheets(ÏnsertList”).Range(“A” & i & ":V" & i).Copy

Thisworkbook.Sheets(“Sheet2”).Range(“A” & i)

End If

Next
```

Try using the above code in one of the modules

Comment: Note: I have added just sheets 1 and 2, please use the same code for rest of the conditions using a nested if else

Comment: Thanks for the help! I still have a couple of problems.
Excel is giving me an error in the VBA pointing to the 1st line "Range(“**A1**”)". I also noticed that the script isnt ran until you actually type in the cells, if i paste something does not work.

Would you know how to solve these?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Irfan, can you help with the above? Thanks

Comment: The first line is to paste list in the "insertsheet" as you mentioned in your problem and the for loop is to loop through all the rows and check for word "Correct". Tell me from where you would paste the list in "insertsheet", will you paste manually or you would take from some other workbook.

Comment: I am pasting something from another workbook. It is always different but the part that matters is in the column E and D. I have some formulas from column N to V determining if the value is correct or not. If it is correct i need that entire row copied up to the column M.


Here is the file i am currently trying to setup. Can you take a look?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vgs4kzhoa1pip0a/CopyRows.xltm 

Much Appreciated!

Comment: Is someone able to help me here? Thanks